# How can I passively check if a user session is still active when using SAML?

Tags: python, saml, saml-2.0

tl;dr: How can a SAML SP validate incoming requests *after* the inisial POST request received from the IdP?

---

NOTE: This is a faily high-level SAML question and the small code-examples below are non-functional and serve for illustration. I would like to understand the "best-practice" when using SAML in an SPA exchanging data via a REST API (the service-provider).

---

I have a JS frontend and a Python back-end. When authenticating, the JS-app triggers a SAML flow on the back-end. This works as intended:

- The browser asks the service-provider (the Python app) to start a login
- The SP response with a redirect to the SAML IdP
- The browser redirects, user authenticates and the IdP sends a POST response back to the SP

All that works fine and I know that user has successfully logged in. I remember basic info using a JWT token in the browser's local-storage.

When I make a request to the Python app, I would like to verify that the session has not been terminated inside the IdP. Especially for critical operations.

From my investigation I gather that this is what the "passive" SAML request is useful for. I'm using the OneLogin Python library for this. But I don't understand how to use these passive requests. When I do the following, all I get is a new redirect URL:

```py
auth = build_onelogin_auth_request()
redirect_url = auth.login(is_passive=True)
#   ^-- what should I do with this URL?
```

I can send that URL back to the browser, making it redirect to the IdP. But that disrupts the user. And it may be a "lossy" reduirect by losing headers and POST payload along the way. I'm not sure if those can be "bundled" into the SAML response. It feels iffy.

I would prefer if the SP could simply "ask" the IdP if the give user-session is still valid and if the rest of the code can continue. For example:

```py
auth = build_onelogin_auth_request()
is_authed = do_something(auth)
#                ^-- What would this need to be?
if not is_authed:
    return 401  # (or 403, whichever is appropriate in the context)
```

Another thing I don't fully grasp is how the SP can make the link between the initial login-request and any followup "check" as discussed above. I can see that the SAML IdP is keeping a session-id. So the IdP can properly identify returning clients. But the SP does not have access to that data. I can see some IDs in the SAML exchanges. But those seem to be request/response IDs. Can they be used by the SP to link an auth-request to an existing session?

Maybe I'm also totally on the wrong path and I would appreciate a reorientation.

For now, from the perspective of the SP I only see the authentication state when the IdP sends the POST response. For any subsequent exchanges between the front-end application (JS) and the SP I am missing that info. I could use expirations on the JWT token and force a fresh SAML exchange when it runs out. But that feels like using the wrong tool for the job.